# Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (spaces and slashes in query)

Tags: jquery, expression, syntax-error

I am trying to query for a button which has a predefined value.

If the query value is as follows, it works fine:

```
_v = "Button1";
```

But as soon as the query value is:

```
_v = "Button 1"; // with spaces
_v = "Button / Button / Button"; // or with slashes
```

the following query fails:

```
$('.club[value=' + _v + ']').addClass('active');
```

and i get the following error:

```
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=Button 1]
```

How do I have to change the query so that it doesn't fail anymore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap the value with double quotes

```
$('.club[value="' + _v + '"]').addClass('active');
```